# Nav2 DWB Controller Trajectory Critics explanation

Tags: microcontroller, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I don't really understand how the DWB Controller Trajectory Critics work. I understand that they are like settings that define how the robot should follow the path created by the Planner server right?

I see that all of them have a parameter named "scale" which is the weighed scale for that critic plugin. How does this work? I mean, the higher this value is, the more important the critic is for the controller? If so, which is the range of this scale parameter?

Thank you in advance for all your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405718/nav2-dwb-controller-trajectory-critics-explanation/) by [marpeja](https://answers.ros.org/users/101482/marpeja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2022-08-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this description [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_dwb_controller/README.md#critic-plugins) has the explanation you are looking for.

> ###Trajectory Generator Plugins
>
> These plugins generate the set of
> possible trajectories that should be
> evaluated by the critics. The
> trajectory with the best score
> determines the output command
> velocity.
> (...)
> ###Critic Plugins
>
> These plugins score the trajectories
> generated by the trajectory generator.
> Multiple plugins can be loaded and the
> sum of their scores determines the
> chosen command velocity.

Your initial thought seems to be correct - it scales these points from each critic, and at the end it adds everything up and chooses the highest score.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marpeja](https://answers.ros.org/users/101482/marpeja/) on 2022-08-30**:
So, as I understand, there is no range for the scale parameter? I can set it to whatever value I want and then, the best trajectory will be the one with the highest score, which it is supposed to match with the highest critic scale set, right?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-30**:
I understand it the same way you wrote :)

**Comment by [marpeja](https://answers.ros.org/users/101482/marpeja/) on 2022-08-30**:
Thank you!